# Is there a way to force the height of an div element?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use "!important" to force the height but nothing is helping. Is there another way to remove extra space on the bottom of this element?

https://jsfiddle.net/zwavbx1e/

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-single-quote.js" async>
      {
      "symbol": "NYSE:BP",
      "width": "50%",
      "height":"10px!important",
      "colorTheme": "light",
      "isTransparent": false,
      "locale": "en"
    }
      </script>
    </div>
    <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the copyright code from the original code.

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright">
      <a
        href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-BP/"
        rel="noopener"
        target="_blank"
        ><span class="blue-text">BP Price Today</span></a
      >
      by TradingView
    </div>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-single-quote.js"
      async
    >
        {
        "symbol": "NYSE:BP",
        "width": 350,
        "colorTheme": "light",
        "isTransparent": false,
        "locale": "en"
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</div>
```

You can reduce it to this to get rid of the text though you might want to check that's your not breaking the copyright rules.

```
        <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"></div>
```

Comment: do you know why "Internet Explorer" doesnt render this. It works on all other browsers.